# Image disappear in Panorama OPENCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, panoramas

I am using opencv and I have a problem.

When I do a 3D panorama, I get this first.

[image]

And when I add the next photo.

[image]

If you see, the left part of the photo dissapear from the Panorama and I dont know why occurs this.

Here is my code

```
 int minHessian = 400;

SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );

std::vector< KeyPoint > keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;

detector.detect( gray_image1, keypoints_object );
 detector.detect( gray_image2, keypoints_scene );

//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
 SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;

extractor.compute( gray_image1, keypoints_object, descriptors_object );
 extractor.compute( gray_image2, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene );

//-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
 BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2,true);
 std::vector< DMatch > matches;
 matcher.match( descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches );

double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
 for( int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ )
 { double dist = matches[i].distance;
 if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
 if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
 }

printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
 printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );

//-- Use only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
 std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

for( int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ )
 { if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist )
 { good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
 }
 std::vector< Point2f > obj;
 std::vector< Point2f > scene;

for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
 {
 //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
 obj.push_back( keypoints_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
 scene.push_back( keypoints_scene[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
 }

// Find the Homography Matrix
//Stich=2
//Ref = 1
Mat T = (Mat_<double>(3,3) <<
                1, 0, image2.cols,
                0, 1, image2.rows,
                0, 0, 1);
/*Mat T = (Mat_<double>(3,3) <<
                    1, 0, 0,
                    0, 1, 0,
                    0, 0, 1);*/
vector<unsigned char> match_mask;
 Mat H = findHomography( scene,obj,match_mask, CV_RANSAC );
 // Use the Homography Matrix to warp the images
 cv::Mat result;
 warpPerspective(image2,result,T*H,cv::Size(image1.cols+image2.cols*2,image1.rows+image2.rows*2));
 cv::Mat half(result,cv::Rect(image2.cols,image2.rows,image1.cols,image1.rows));
 image1.copyTo(half);
 result=deleteBlackZone(result);

 imshow( "Result", result );
 imwrite("Panorama.jpg",result);
```

Anyone knows how can I repair this and no image dissapear? Anyone have a code for C++ functional for this? To see it and look what I am doing bad.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

The code of deleteBlackZone()

```
Mat deleteBlackZone(const Mat &image)
{
Mat resultGray;
Mat result;
image.copyTo(result);

 cout<<"Deleting "<< image.channels()<<endl;
 cvtColor( image, resultGray, CV_RGB2GRAY );

     medianBlur(resultGray,resultGray,3);
     Mat resultTh;
        vector<vector<Point> > contours;
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

        threshold(resultGray,resultTh,1,255,0);
        findContours( resultTh, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        Mat dsta= Mat::zeros(image.rows,image.cols, CV_8UC3);

        cout<<"Deleteado"<<endl;
                    Mat besta= Mat(contours[0]);
                    int max_areaa = -1;
                    int buenoa=0;
                    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) {
                            /**1
                             * mosa
                             * Imagen de destino, los contornos, el numero de contorno, el color del contorno (en este caso es negro para marcarlos)
                             * la anchura de linea, la union entre lineas, informacion sobre la jerarquia, maximo nivel de dibujo (si fuese mayor
                             * que 0, dibujaria los contornos que cuelgan de el) y por ultimo el offset
                             */
                            if(contourArea(contours[i])> max_areaa)
                            {
                                max_areaa=contourArea(contours[i]);
                                besta=Mat(contours[i]);
                                buenoa=i;
                                cout << i << endl;
                            }
                    }
                    Rect a = boundingRect(besta);
                    cv::Mat half(result,a);
                    return half;
        /// Encontrar contornos
        /*
         * Imagen de entrada, conjunto de contornos, vector que contne informacion topologica de la imagen(mismo numero que contornos)
         * el modo de recuperacion (en este caso, crea una jerarquia de cotornos anidados), modo de ejecucion (comprime horizontal,
         * vertical y diagonalmente los segmentos y deja solo los puntos (por ejemplo, en un rectangulo, el contorno son 4 puntos)
         * y por ultimo el offset usado
         */
     cout<<"Deleteado"<<endl;
        findContours( resultTh, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
     Mat dst= Mat::zeros(image.rows,image.cols, CV_8UC3);


        cout<<"Deleteado"<<endl;
        Mat best= Mat(contours[0]);
        int max_area = -1;
        int bueno=0;
        for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) {
                /**1
                 * mosa
                 * Imagen de destino, los contornos, el numero de contorno, el color del contorno (en este caso es negro para marcarlos)
                 * la anchura de linea, la union entre lineas, informacion sobre la jerarquia, maximo nivel de dibujo (si fuese mayor
                 * que 0, dibujaria los contornos que cuelgan de el) y por ultimo el offset
                 */
                if(contourArea(contours[i]) > max_area)
                {
                    max_area=contourArea(contours[i]);
                    best=Mat(contours[i]);
                    bueno=i;
                    cout << i << endl;
                }
        }
        cout<<"Deleteado"<<endl;
        Mat approxCurve;

        approxPolyDP(Mat(best),approxCurve,0.01*arcLength(Mat(best),true),true);
        cout<<"DeleteadoFFFF"<<endl;
        Scalar color=  Scalar(255, 255, 255);
        cout<<bueno<<endl;
        /*for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) {
                /**
                 * Imagen de destino, los contornos, el numero de contorno, el color del contorno (en este caso es negro para marcarlos)
                 * la anchura de linea, la union entre lineas, informacion sobre la jerarquia, maximo nivel de dibujo (si fuese mayor
                 * que 0, dibujaria los contornos que cuelgan de el) y por ultimo el offset
                 */
        /*      drawContours( dst, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
            }

        //imshow("corregida",dst);*/
        //Guardo el mejor contorno
        drawContours( dst, contours, bueno, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
        imwrite("Contorno2.jpg",dst);

     exit(1);
     return image;
}
```

Comment: can you remove the `result=deleteBlackZone(result);` call and tell us whether the image part still disappears?

Comment: If I dont delete the black zones, I cant join the next image, i need to delete them.

Comment: are you sure that the problem isn't within that `deleteBlackZone` function? Can you for example delte only the black zone from the first image pair and dont do it for the second, just for testing?

Comment: or add a `imshow("intermediate result", result); waitKey(-1);` before  `result=deleteBlackZone(result);` then you can see the intermediate result and press any key to continue

Comment: I add the code of deleteBlackZone. Now i am going to see the intermediate result.

Comment: Is not that the image disappears, it's simply that the image was warped. If you notice, the entire building in the picture *bends over* and a small part of the leftmost image is lost in this process.

Comment: NO, the image is the same except from the black area, so the deleteBlackZone no is the failure